# Error on saving to local storage for Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue JS app I am trying to save data I get back from a rest api into a list component but I am getting the following error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"
```

I can't see what could be causing this?

**Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="mb-5 mt-5 container">

    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
        My List
        <span class="badge badge-light">{{List.length}}</span>
      </a>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        v-for="(result, index) in List"
        :key="index"
      >
        {{result.collectionName}}
        <br>
        <b>{{result.artistName}}</b>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button
              class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"
              v-on:click="removeElement(index)"
            >Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button
              class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block"
              @click="toiTunesAlbum(result)"
            >View on iTunes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info mt-5 btn-lg btn-block" @click="saveList()">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "List",
  props: ["List"],

  mounted() {
    if(localStorage.result) this.result = JSON.parse(this.result);
  },

  methods: {
      saveList() {
      localStorage.result = this.result;
      localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(this.result));   
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(this.result + 'List Saved');
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
    },

    removeElement: function(index) {
      this.List.splice(index, 1);
    },

    resizeArtworkUrl(result) {
      return result.artworkUrl100.replace("100x100", "160x160");
    },
    toiTunesAlbum(result) {
      window.open(result.collectionViewUrl, "_blank");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.album-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.album-container {
  height: 350px;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas on how I can save to local storage the rest api result that would be great. Should I be using the List array or result?

Comment: Should `JSON.parse(this.result)` be `JSON.parse(localStorage.result)`?

Comment: Even changing it to that I still get the same error....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are only initializing this.result if localStorage.result has a value. If localStorage.result doesn’t have a value the first time you call saveList this.result is still undefined.  Try setting a default value or skip trying to save if the value is still undefined. I am also not sure of the relationship between this.List and this.result, since List seems to be a list of results?